# How to include Http request method name in client method names generated with NSwag

Tags: c#, openapi, nswag

When I generate a C# client for an API using NSwag,
where the API includes endpoints that can be used with multiple Http request types (e.g. POST, GET)
the client generates a method for each request with the same base name, plus a number.

E.g. Using this API: https://api.premiumfunding.net.au/assets/scripts/swagger/v1/swagger.json

The schema contains an endpoint `/contract` that supports `GET` and `POST` requests, and an endpoint `/contract/{ID}` that supports `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests.

The generated client has methods:

- `ContractAsync` for GET requests without ID
- `Contract2Async` for POST requests without ID
- `Contract3Async` for GET requests with ID
- `Contract4Async` for POST requests with ID
- `Contract5Async` for DELETE requests with ID

I would like it to generate methods named:

- `GetContractAsync` for GET requests without ID
- `PostContractAsync` for POST requests without ID
- `GetContractAsync` for GET requests with ID (method overload)
- `PostContractAsync` for POST requests with ID (method overload)
- `DeleteContractAsync` for DELETE requests with ID

At the moment I am just renaming the methods manually.

**Is it possible to configure NSwag to generated these method names?**

(Or is there an alternative tool that will give me this result?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement and provide an own IOperationNameGenerator:

https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.CodeGeneration/OperationNameGenerators/IOperationNameGenerator.cs

Another option would be to preprocess the spec and change the “operationId”s to the form “controller_operation” (simple console app based on the NSwag.Core package)

Comment: I did not find an example on how to plug in my own IOperationNameGenerator in my MVC app. I would have expected that the configuration passed to services.AddSwaggerDocument would have a provision for that. I would appreciate a code example "for dummies".