# NSwagStudio, include Http request method name in client method names generated with NSwag

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, nswagstudio

I generate an Angular client for a.Net Core 3.1 API using NSwagStudio.
The API includes endpoints that can be used with multiple Http request types (e.g. POST, GET).
The client generates a method for each request with the same base name, plus a number.

The schema contains an endpoint `/contract` that supports `GET` and `POST` requests, and an endpoint `/contract/{ID}` that supports `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests.

The generated client has methods like :

- `ContractAsync` for GET requests without ID
- `Contract2Async` for POST requests without ID
- `Contract3Async` for GET requests with ID
- `Contract4Async` for POST requests with ID
- `Contract5Async` for DELETE requests with ID

I would like it to generate methods named:

- `GetContractAsync` for GET requests without ID
- `PostContractAsync` for POST requests without ID

etc

The answer to the question is to "implement and provide an own IOperationNameGenerator"
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49935417/4180382

I have no clue how to implement and provide this IOperationNameGenerator.

The "Web Api via reflection" tab contains several custom implementations but doesn't mention "IOperationNameGenerator"

How do I implement IOperationNameGenerator?

Comment: Did you manage to find out?

Comment: @gerb0n No I didn't!

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to provide a custom `IOperationNameGenerator` either, but I was able to changed the generated OperationIDs, and thus the generated client method names, using an `IOperationProcessor` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56191275/310446).

Answer (score 6):

In your Startup.cs do this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.CustomOperationIds(d => d.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor 
       ? controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.Name
       : d.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo?.Name);
});
```

The same can also be set via `c.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.OperationIdSelector`

Note that `ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo?.Name` is the default I used from the source code [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/60b018c7b83e6acc57b44ee905155524d0fbca3a/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SwaggerGenerator/SwaggerGeneratorOptions.cs#L64)